# Stripe - possible for zero quantity subscription

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a subscription plan on stripe, and use this for per seat pricing.

The specific use case is:

- Customer has previously paid and so has customer id and subscription id in the database
- They remove all of their users one month
- The next month they add a user again
- I want the end date to have been updated to the end of the current month when the bill period rolls over, so that I don't display a message saying they didn't pay for previous bill period.

In the stripe subscription object, can I set the quantity for the subscription to 0, meaning the customer won't get billed?

If I do this, will the webhook for invoice.payment_succeeded still be called? This allows me to update information in the database.

Is there a different webhook I should be using for this?

Comment: what is your problem exactly? what I got is you have a plan in stripe which gets charge monthly and when payment succeeded webhook come it updates your database. And in this, you also update last payment into DB. For some month you don't want to charge customer right?

Comment: I want to know if setting quantity to 0 will mean customers are not charged. And if so, will the payment_succeeded webhook still call on the payment date to allow me to update details

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes if you will set quantity of subscription to 0 then still a zero dollar invoice still come in payment_succeeded webhook and will update the invoice.

Comment: Does the customer get charged for $0 total? May seem like a dumb question but want to know if they'll get a receipt for $0, etc.

Comment: Nothing will be deducted from the customer's account but yes a $0 invoice will be added to the customer's account.

Comment: Just added to account or emailed?